# In Mathematica, how to make Interpolation as good as ListLinePlot？

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

First, I learned from
[In Mathematica, what interpolation function is ListPlot using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856461/in-mathematica-what-interpolation-function-is-listplot-using/3864709#3864709)
that the the method used by ListPlot for interpolation is to interpolate each coordinate as a function of the list index. And I think the ListLinePlot can decide which InterpolationOrder should be taken.
If I change the InterpolationOrder -> 3 into InterpolationOrder -> 1 , the intepolation of my data is more like the plot of ListLinePlot. 
Here is the data and code:

So, is there any way I can interpolate my data and plot it as good as ListLinePlot do? Or is there any way to make my interpolation more "clever", so it can also decide the InterpolationOrder itself?
Here is the data and code:

```
mypoint = {{1.3336020610508064`, 
0.05630827677109675`}, {1.5103543939292194`, 
0.05790550283922009`}, {1.6927497417380886`, 
0.07151008153610137`}, {1.840047310044461`, 
0.11741226450605104`}, {1.9209270855795286`, 
0.2726755425789721`}, {1.953407919235778`, 
2.0759615023390294`}, {1.9550995254889463`, 0.7164793699550908`}};
interpcut[r_, x_] := Module[{s}, s = SortBy[r, First];
Piecewise[{{0, x < First[s][[1]]}, {0, 
 x > Last[s][[1]]}, {Interpolation[r, InterpolationOrder -> 3][x],
  True}}]];
Interpolation1[x_] := interpcut[mypoint, x];
ListPlot[mypoint, PlotStyle -> Orange]
ListLinePlot[mypoint, PlotStyle -> Orange]
Plot[Interpolation1[x], {x, 1.3, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

thanks,
 Jzm

For the question of @agentp:

```
mypoint1 = {{1.3336020610508064`, 
0.05630827677109675`}, {1.5103543939292194`, 
0.05790550283922009`}, {1.6927497417380886`, 
0.07151008153610137`}, {1.840047310044461`, 
0.11741226450605104`}, {1.9209270855795286`, 
0.2726755425789721`}, {1.953407919235778`, 
2.0759615023390294`}, {1.9550995254889463`, 0.7164793699550908`}};
interpcut[r_, x_] := Module[{s},(*sort array by x coord*)s = SortBy[r, First];
Piecewise[{{0, x < First[s][[1]] + 0.002}, {0, 
 x > Last[s][[1]] - 0.002}, {Interpolation[r][x], True}}]];
Group1point = ListPlot[mypoint1, PlotStyle -> Red];
Group1Interpolation[x_] := interpcut[mypoint1, x];
Group1line = Plot[Group1Interpolation[x], {x, 1.3, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[{Group1point, Group1line}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: `ListLinePlot`'s  default interpolation order is 1,  and if you set `InterpolationOrder -> 1` you get the exact same plot. (It seems like you knew that, so what are you asking? )

Comment: I think the ListLinePlot can change the  interpolation automaticaly.

Comment: I believe agentp is correct that there is no automagic in `ListLinePlot` with respect to `InterpolationOrder`. I used a value of three in the answer you cite because that was what the question requested.

Comment: the docs actually say the default is "None". If there is some example where it doesnt simply draw straight lines between points that woild be interesting to see.

Comment: Should be asked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/